# How to build authorization service with NestJS?

Tags: typescript, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js, nestjs

I need to build a dedicated authorization service with NestJS.
It needs to be a provider for authorization like google or discord (OAuth2).
To clarify, I will provide an example. It follows:

I got some projects, all of which need to authenticate and authorize users.
And a user has one account on all these projects.
So when a user wants to sign up or sign in, we redirect them to the abovementioned authorization service.
There the user creates an account.
Then the authorization service redirects the user back to the project.
And then the project asks (sending a query string with some code) the service to provide a token for this user.
After getting it, the project grants the user with this token.
Upon following requests, the user will provide this token to access the project's protected resources.
Also, some mechanism to revoke, refresh tokens must be in place.

I tried to google, but didn't find much useful articles.
Can somebody provide some helpful links to articles or docs, SO threads, anything of help would be appreciated.
For now the stack I am using for a backend is NestJS with Passport.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post now, but I believe the OP's original intent was to create an OAuth2 server, operating as an identity service provider for client applications - not a client application for an established third-party authentication service. The OP also specifies that they are using the NestJS framework for their stack and are using the Passport authentication middleware.

While Gary Archer's answer recommends an excellent off-the-shelf solution in Curity, it's possible that the OP or other users coming here may be looking to implement something a little more 'hands-on' in code: whether for their own learning, or as an integration to another project. Below are the general steps I took when taking on a similar project myself - I'm not going to get too prescriptive here as the specifics will vary by project!

### Read up on OAuth2

Prior to attempting this, I'd recommend making sure you're comfortable with the core mechanics of OAuth2 - especially the 'Authorization Code' grant type process, as that's most likely the one you'll be using for most user-interactive applications. [Digital Ocean have produced an excellent guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) that's well worth a read before diving into the code. Even if you know the basics of how OAuth2 works, it's worth taking a quick refresher - trust me, if you don't have a solid grasp of this, you'll run into trouble later!

### Implementing an OAuth2 Server

Regarding implementation of the OAuth2 server, the following GitHub project may be of interest: https://github.com/toondaey/nestjs-oauth2-server. It provides the necessary framework to implement a completely custom OAuth2 server in NestJS. As specified in the documentation, it requires the developer to provide a model to integrate with the identity store and implement validation, and it will also require configuration of the handler endpoints.

All of this should be reasonably straightforward for a typical implementation, where a simple OAuth2 identity provider is all that is required, with authorisation and other functionality being handled internally by the client application. At a minimum, you'll need to tell the auth server how to store and retrieve required data, provide any validation logic for things like scope checks, and create at least one handler endpoint for client authentication.

*(Note that [there has been some discussion on the above linked project's issues regarding dependency injection](https://github.com/toondaey/nestjs-oauth2-server/issues/72) that may create issues if you're using an ORM with your model - check the thread for some proposed solutions if this is a problem for you)*

### Client Authentication

Per the OP's stated assumptions, if the above solution is implemented as a dedicated standalone OAuth2 service, then it should be simple to integrate authentication via this service using [Passport's generic OAuth2 strategy](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-oauth2/).

Answer (score 0):

It feels like OAuth will be your best option, though there is a learning curve. It would be worth breaking down your question further though - and I will update my answer if needed.

OAuth involves outsourcing the security to an Authorization Server (AS) which your apps call over HTTP(S):

- Authenticate in many ways - Google and others
- Manage sign-up, credential storage etc
- Identify users in your APIs and authorize the same in all cases

If this feels like I am on track then here are a couple of options for getting started:

**FREE AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

Choose one of these options, both of which act as 'black boxes', providing HTTP endpoints:

- Cloud system, eg AWS, Azure
- An option you can run yourself in a Docker container

I usually recommend the second type for people getting started, since they are better educationally - and also provide good options for things like connecting to your own data sources. Here are a couple of example providers:

- [Curity Community Edition](https://curity.io/resources/getting-started/)
- [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/)

**FREE CLIENT**

Developing web and mobile clients is tricky, so start with [OAuth Tools](https://oauth.tools/), to get a pretty good client for free - very handy for testing.

**KEEP CODE STANDARDS BASED**

It should not matter which option you choose - follow standard patterns, as recommended by my company in [Curity Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/) and you can switch later.

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this will help](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs), its for google sheets, but the process should be pretty much the same for anything using OAuth2. Read the example code very carefully, it's a bit tricky.

The main things you need to do is:

1. Create and endpoint for the OAuth2 redirect, it will have a query param called `code`
2. Create the link to google's OAuth API, fx `google.com/?redirect=foo.com/oauth/redirect` (This will pretty much always contain the redirect url, as well as the permissions your app has over the user's account)
3. Send the user to the URL we generated in 2. when they return they will be redirected to the endpoint we created in 1. and their token will be a query param called `code`
4. Generate the refresh token, and any other "housekeeping" you want with the tokens
5. Now you need to perform a query/request to google, asking for information about the user (i.e. username/email), part of this request will contain the user's token we got in 3./4. so google doesn't just give the info to any rando.

Hopefully that answered your question, I had a bit of a tough time understanding what you specifically wanted from this, so feel free to ask more.

Comment: Let me clarify a little.
I want to build one authorization service for several projects.
Maybe OAuth 2.0 was misleading.
All I meant is a user registers with email/password at my service. And then they can access my other services using this account.
It's like when you use google account to access youtube, gdrive and google keep.
One company, one account and several services.
This is the core functionality.

Comment: I would suggest that you create a login/auth microservice, which your existing apps can query for information or add/remove users (then you can also block any requests coming from external sources). I'm not too sure what your stack looks like but hopefully it wont be too hard to integrate/host something like this. From there I can see a few ways you can proceed: using a message broker, rest or graphql. I would suggest using graphql because cooler than a rest api.

Comment: If you don't want to build it yourself. You might also be able to use something like Auth0, I haven't used it much but I think it allows for the kind of functionality you want.